# Rails ActiveRecord has_many assocation with same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on implementing product bundles in an existing site. I have a `Product` model with various product types in an enum that I have added a product type of "bundle" to.

I want to be able to create a product with a product_type of bundle that will contain multiple products of other types. So, for example, a bundle might contain multiple books.

I have a `BundleProduct` model and database table for storing the associations, containing only this:

```
class BundleProduct < ApplicationRecord 
    belongs_to :bundle,  :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => 'bundle_id'
    belongs_to :product, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => 'product_id'
end
```

This is the relevant code from my `Product` model, simplified a bit for this example:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    enum :product_type => { :book => 1, :supplies => 2, :bundle => 3 } 
    has_many :bundle_products, :foreign_key => :bundle_id, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In the Rails console, I can run `product.bundle_products` to get an empty array, and if I create records in the `bundle_products` table directly, the objects are shown correctly.

However, when I try to save the record via the Rails app I get a `RecordNotFound` exception. The form I'm using is a pretty basic edit form for the bundle product, with a list of checkboxes to select other products to be included in the bundle.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all BundleProducts with 'id': (309, 12, 225)
(found 0 results, but was looking for 3). Couldn't find BundleProducts with ids 309, 12, 225.
```

The parameter submitted by my form for these associated records is simply this (irrelevant attributes omitted):

```
{"product"=>{"bundle_product_ids"=>["309", "12", "225"]}}
```

My controller is just calling `product.update!(product_params)` when saving the parent record, and for the purposes of troubleshooting this I have all parameters explicitly permitted via `params.require(:product).permit!`.

ActiveRecord is looking for BundleProducts with those IDs when it should be looking for Products. My gut feeling is that I'm thinking about this relationship all wrong but I've been unable to find a comparable issue here on SO about it.

What am I doing wrong? Did I just miss a step or is my approach completely wrong for what I want to do?

I'm running Rails 6.1 with MariaDB.

**Update:** I was running the above in the Rails console. When I submit a form for creating a product with the associated bundle via my admin UI, I found this in the development log, which seems to point to the issue:

```
BundleProduct Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `bundle_products`.*
  FROM `bundle_products` WHERE `bundle_products`.`id` IN (309, 12, 225)
```

It's looking for bundle_product records by ID, which it shouldn't be. It should be looking in the `product_id` column for those values.

This suggests I have my association wrong somehow but I'm not sure where I went wrong. My `bundle_products` table has the following columns only:

```
pry(main)> BundleProduct.column_names
=> ["id", "created_at", "updated_at", "bundle_id", "product_id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

So yes, `bundle_product_ids` is the name of the associated `BundleProduct` IDs. You'd need a `:through` association like `has_many :bundled_products, through: :bundle_products, class_name: "Product"` (you might need a `:source` too). And then you could have `bundled_product_ids`.

Comment: Thanks. This did need a source, so my model now has this:
```
has_many :bundle_products, :foreign_key => :bundle_id, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :bundled_products, :through => :bundle_products, :class_name => 'Product', :source => :product
```
Now I'm getting this error in the console, which seems to suggest I'm missing a column/attribute:
```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute '_method' for Product.
from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-6.1.7.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `_assign_attribute'
```

Comment: Looks like I can't use Markdown here. Sorry for the unreadable mess.

Comment: `_method` is the name of the attribute Rails adds to indicate a `DELETE`, `PUT` or `PATCH` operation because HTML doesn't support those methods in forms (only `GET` and `POST`). How that attribute ended up in your `params[:product]` I don't know, seems very odd.

Answer (score 0):

In designing a data model, you will sometimes find a model that should have a relation to itself. For example, you may want to store all employees in a single database model, but be able to trace relationships such as between manager and subordinates. This situation can be modeled with **self-joining associations**:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id"

  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee", optional: true
end
```

**OR**

First, you must add a new column named *'type'* in the **Product** Table, whose datatype will be a string.

After that, you have to change the Product model below.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bundle_products, class_name: 'BundleProduct', foreign_key: 'bundle_id', dependent: :destroy
end
```

After that, you have to change the **BundleProduct** model below.

```
class BundleProduct < Product
  belongs_to :product, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'bundle_id', optional: true
end
```

And if you want, you can do the rest for Supply and Book models.

Make sure *'bundle_id', 'book_id', and 'supply_id'* are present in the **Product** Table, whose datatype will be a integer.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bundle_products, class_name: 'BundleProduct', foreign_key: 'bundle_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :book_products, class_name: 'BookProduct', foreign_key: 'book_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :supply_products, class_name: 'SupplyProduct', foreign_key: 'supply_id', dependent: :destroy
end


class BundleProduct < Product
  belongs_to :product, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'bundle_id', optional: true
end

class BookProduct < Product
  belongs_to :product, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'book_id', optional: true
end

class SupplyProduct < Product
  belongs_to :product, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'supply_id', optional: true
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. However, this is somewhat complicated by the fact that I'm not using single-table inheritance for the different product types. All products are just Product objects, and I can differentiate between them by using the product_type enum shown in the second code snippet in my post above.